# why link_to doesn't work(rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have model User. And one of controller methods is

```
 def view_messages
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @message=Message.new
    @messages=@user.messages.reverse
  end
```

Also i have model Message , and one of parametres of this model is user_from:integer

view_messages view have

```
render :partial => 'messages/message', :collection => @messages
```

and _message.haml have

```
= content_tag_for(:li,message) do
  %p
    From:
    =link_to User.find(message.user_from).name,User.find(message.user_from)
```

it writes an error

> Couldn't find User without an ID

but if i want to print it like

```
 = content_tag_for(:li,message) do
      %p
        From:
        =message.user_from
```

it print it ( for exaple it prints 2) , so why it cant find user with id 2 if i have this user? What i am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: please help. very need to solve this problem

Comment: How does `@user.messages` work? I guess it's not a `has_many` relation, judging from your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General issues:

1. `user_from` should be `user_from_id`, by Rails convention
2. Then you should have a belongs_to relation:

   ```
   class Message
     belongs_to :user_from
   end
   ```

   which will automatically pull the user from the database
3. Then you can refer to the user as an attribute of Message

   ```
   link_to @message.user_from.name, @message.user_from
   ```

Check *all* of the Message records. One of them probably has no `user_from`, and causes the error.

Comment: thanks. i am newbie / i will try to follow all ruby conventions. You were right,i needed to reset my database, cause old messages didnt had parameter :user_from

Comment: and you should do `@user = User.find(params[:id]).include(:messages)`

Comment: generally speaking your current infrastructure is terrible in terms of performance and db queries